Node auto creating static files for top level request
I have a React application deployed to Azure App Service. When accessing the application if I enter the base URL followed by a space and a filename it is redirecting me to the appropriate page but it is also creating a file in sources. For example https://myportal.myapp.net/ .testfile is creating a file in sources called .testfile (see screenshot):


What is driving this behavior and how can I prevent it? I can't tell if this is a webpack, node, or App Service issue where it sees that file as a static asset to be served.
